# Elasticsearch search query priority (full match -> substring -> fuzzy)

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, fuzzy-search, n-gram, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying to make query sorted by elastic according to following priorities: firstly, it shows all results which are exact as search string. Then it show all results which have search string as the substring. And finally, it shows all fuzzy matches.

*Example*:

search: **Infect**

results:

1. infect (exact match)
2. infected people, infection is spreading, ... (substring)
3. impacted smth, I fetched ... (fuzzy match)

Comment: I think is the same question as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60770188/how-to-give-different-weights-to-exact-phonetic-and-fuzzy-queries/60815133#60815133

Comment: The solution by @LucE should work. If not, there is another that isn't optimal but it will work for sure, use mget and basically do 3 queries in one http round trip and concat the results on application level. This way the mget request will contain 3 get requests wherre every get request is contains the category that you want